# How to disable my fullpage script from my members in wordpress?

Tags: html, wordpress

How to disable my fullpage script only for my registered members in wordpress? This is my fullpage script code

```
<script src="https://linkvertise.net/cdn/linkvertise.js"></script><script>linkvertise(11261, {whitelist: ["dropmb.com"], blacklist: []});</script>

<script src="https://linkvertise.net/cdn/linkvertise.js"></script><script>linkvertise(15361, {whitelist: ["verystream.com"], blacklist: []});</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a function [`is_user_logged_in()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_user_logged_in/)

Comment: How can I do that? I don't really know how to use that function. Can you help me please?